# Silverlight Responding Late

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I'm working on a Silverlight project using the MVVM pattern. The application is deployed to a remote location. While browsing the remote application url, I'm getting a late response though the same application code is working fine locally.

What do I need to check for on the server? Is Silverlight plugin causing any issue? I have Silverlight 5.0

I'm using Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit OS and IE 11

**edit**:

getting alert as below,

[image]

Comment: Silverlight is not ASP.NET

Comment: @Stilgar what's the point you're trying to make?

Comment: @Rohaan, are you implying that the web server and the Silverlight app are located on separate servers?

Comment: First of all I want to remove the confusion and second I suggest that the question will become more clear if the OP says which part is slow the Silverlight part or the services part (presumably ASP.NET)

Comment: @Stilgar sure thing, I agree that the question needs more details...I just didn't get your first comment...I wasn't confused about Silverlight and ASP.NET and the question doesn't seem to imply that "Silverlight is ASP.NET"

Comment: The question was edited multiple times :)

Comment: is there anything that i need to update on remote server?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen this exact error before, but this appears to be an error coming from the browser itself. It simply means that that Silverlight is stuck in a loop, or is running a very lengthy process on the UI thread. If the UI thread is locked up for a long period of time, the browser will complain about it.

If you are using something WCF, or REST, you will be using these services will be ran asynchronously and not on the UI thread. This will mean that the app will remain responsive, and the browser will not complain. However, if you lock up the UI thread, you will invoke the wrath of the browser. So, my advice is to simply step through the code and find out where the application is spending a lot of time and getting stuck. Methods that accidentally call themselves and eventually cause a stack overflow are often a cause of this.

If in fact, you are running a lengthy process on the UI thread, you should move it to a background thread with the use of the BackgroundWorker class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.100).aspx

You can also use the async/await pattern in Silverlight, but it's not very straight forward to get it working in Silverlight. You need to include the async/await BCL NuGet package to get it working because Silverlight doesn't have async/await functionality out of the box.